# JavaScript/GraphQL add fragments conditionally

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have a JavaScript function that sends a fetch request to a graphQL endpoint. My goal is to add a fragment to my graphQL query based a parameter passed into the JavaScript function, for example, my function looks like this:

```
const getEvent = async (id, lang) => {
    const data = await fetchAPI(`
        fragment EventFields on Event {
            title
            slug
            date
        }
        fragment BnFields on Event {
            bn {
                content
                subtitle
            }
        }
        query fetchEvent($id: ID!, $idType: EventIdType!) {
            event(id: $id, idType: $idType) {
                ...EventFields
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add the `BnFields` fragment if the lang parameter to the `getEvent` function equals `bn`. I know I can achieve this by declaring two separate queries depending on the `lang` parameter, but I was wondering if there's a more optimum way inside the graphQL itself to add a fragment based on a variable. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The `getEvent` function you posted appears incomplete. Can you please [edit] it to include the actual code?

Comment: @xadm please do not make unnecessary edits.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is precisely what an `@include` directive is good for:

```
query fetchEvent($id: ID!, $idType: EventIdType!, $isBn: Boolean!) {
    event(id: $id, idType: $idType) {
        ...EventFields
        ...BnFields @include(if: $isBn)
        content
    }
}
```

Then, add `isBn: lang === 'bn'` to the variables you are passing along with the query.